# Where-object filter is not working with get-childitem for remote machine

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I'm trying to copy a [msi](/questions/tagged/msi) package from remote machine but `Where-Object` filter doesn't works with `Get-ChildItem`

```
get-childitem -path $comp –recurse | Copy-Item -Destination "\\10.35.10.91\C$\dest"
```

# works, it copies msi file to local machine

```
get-childitem -path $comp –recurse | where-object {$PSItem.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).addDays(-1)} | Copy-Item -Destination "\\10.35.10.91\C$\dest"
```

# not working, here the `where-object` filter is not working

Comment: And what is in the $comp variable? Shouldn't you include some filtering? Like -include *.msi

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: $Comp variable define path from which msi file needs to be taken

Comment: I want to copy latest msi pkg from .140 shared machine into server and install that pkg onto server . now condition is it should get only the latest msi pkg or build.  scenario is deployment of latest build